# FFMPEG parameter 'pixel_aspect' out of range

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to extract thumbnail from video using ffmpeg but I am getting following error. Video taken from Ipad and and flipped horizontally.

```
/var/www/html/ffmpeg -i "/var/www/html/media/4/event-4-video-setting-17.mp4" -r 1 -ss 00:00:03 -vframes 1 "/var/www/html/media/4/new_file.jpg"
ffmpeg version N-63893-gc69defd Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul 16 2014 05:38:01 with gcc 4.6 (Debian 4.6.3-1)
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg-static/64bit --extra-cflags='-I/root/ffmpeg-static/64bit/include -static' --extra-ldflags='-L/root/ffmpeg-static/64bit/lib -static' --extra-libs='-lxml2 -lexpat -lfreetype' --enable-static --disable-shared --disable-ffserver --disable-doc --enable-bzlib --enable-zlib --enable-postproc --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-gray --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-libvpx
  libavutil      52. 89.100 / 52. 89.100
  libavcodec     55. 66.101 / 55. 66.101
  libavformat    55. 43.100 / 55. 43.100
  libavdevice    55. 13.101 / 55. 13.101
  libavfilter     4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/var/www/html/media/4/event-4-video-setting-17.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2015-09-08 07:03:47
  Duration: 00:00:05.45, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5048 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m), 480x640, 5042 kb/s, SAR -1:1 DAR -3:4, 28.42 fps, 29.97 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 180
      creation_time   : 2015-09-08 07:03:47
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      encoder         : H.264
[buffer @ 0x3183060] Value -1.000000 for parameter 'pixel_aspect' out of range [0 - 1.79769e+308]
    Last message repeated 3 times
[buffer @ 0x3183060] Error setting option pixel_aspect to value -1/1.
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x318b620] Error applying options to the filter.
Error opening filters!
```

Comment: The first thing you should do is use a more up-to-date version of ffmpeg

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here, I have created a function that accepts 2 parameters video path & thumbnail path respectively.

```
function videoThumbnail($video,$thumbImage){
  $ffmpeg = FFMPEGPATH; // Path to the ffmpeg library linux file
  exec("$ffmpeg -y -i '$video' -r 1 -ss 00:00:00 -vframes 1 '$thumbImage'".' 2>&1', $result);
// Here $result is used for debugging purpose.
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this actually resolves the particular issue in the question. See the answer by @aergistal for a more probable solution. Also, the `-r 1` and `-ss 00:00:00` are superfluous.

Answer (score 3):

You somehow have negative values for the Sample Aspect Ratio (SAR) and Display Aspect Ratio (DAR):

`SAR -1:1 DAR -3:4`

Try to use a filter to set them correctly:

`-filter:v "setsar=1/1,setdar=3/4"`